# TypeError: jQuery(...).htmlarea is not a function

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jhtmlarea

I'm using a WordPress site.I'm create new plugins WP.

When I use "jHtmlArea Editor" after script load, I get this error

TypeError: jQuery(...).htmlarea is not a function

```
 jQuery("#txtDefaultHtmlArea").htmlarea();
```

I have no idea what is causing it or what it even means. If I don't use WordPress. It is OK

Comment: Are you sure you include your script in page? Don't you have other errors in console before this?

Comment: htmlarea is not an standardfunction of jquery